# Sign-In as different users types

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm very new to JAVA so this is probably an easy solution.

I'm looking to design a login system using differnt users from a database.

They are seperated by a "Yes" column in the database.

It currently signs in the manager using the IF statement but stops there and won't sign in when using credetials of a staff member.

```
 signIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {

                    try{
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    // Connection to the Database
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");

                    // Gets text from textfields and assigns them to variables
                    s1 = tfUsername.getText();
                    s2 = tfPassword.getText();

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();   

                    // SQL Statements 
                    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login WHERE UName= '"+s1+"' and PWord = '"+s2+"'");

                    // Extracts data from statement to a result set
                    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

                    if (rs.next())
                    {
                        String Username = rs.getString("UName");
                        String Password = rs.getString("PWord");
                        String staff = rs.getString("Staff");
                        String management = rs.getString("Management");
                        if(Username.equals(s1) & Password.equals(s2) & management.equals("Yes"))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful, Hello " + s1 );
                            ManagerDashboard.main(args);
                            signInFrame.setVisible(false);

                        }
                        if(Username.equals(s1) & Password.equals (s2) & staff.equals("Yes"))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful, Hello " + s1);
                            StaffDashboard.main(args);
                            signInFrame.setVisible(false);

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed");
                    }
                    }
                    // SQL Catch block to catch errors
                    catch(SQLException s){


                    }
                    // Catch block to catch ActionListener errors
                    catch (Exception e1){

                    }

                };

            });
```

Comment: does the database and the sign in have both UPPER case or both LOWER case?

Comment: @isaace I don't really understand your question. The syntax is correct. The capitals and everything is fine

Comment: I am just making a small point that the equals method only return true if the case matches.

Comment: @isaace Any ideas mate?

Comment: you need to use a debugger to see the values of your variables while the program is running. Another option is to System.out.println() your variables all over the place which should help you find what's causing the issue.

Comment: You should not be catching Exceptions and not printing their stack traces. If an exception occurs, you will have no way of knowing that it did, and your program will be impossible to debug.

Comment: @RickRidley Doesnt it need to be wrapped in a try/catch? how do i get it to print errors so i can see?

Comment: Invocations of methods that throw checked exceptions need to be wrapped in a try catch block (or the exception needs to be propogated to the parent method using `throws`). You can apply logic in catch blocks to capture the fact that an exception occurred. In your case, you should be at least doing something like `e.printStackTrace()` within your catch blocks. When an exception is thrown, you will be able to see what caused the exception.